# cannot assign IP to tun / tap interface because the error : System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate

Tags: ubuntu, network-programming, windows-subsystem-for-linux, tun

Hello I've created a tun tap interface inside WSL2,with the following commands :

```
chown root.users /dev/net/tun
chmod g+rw /dev/net/tun
tunctl -t tap0 -u username
ifconfig tap0 up
```

at this point I tried to assign an IP address to it,but this is what happens :

```
root@DESKTOP-N9UN2H3:/mnt/i/macos-haxm# dhclient tap0
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
```

how can I fix that ?